# Printing Time and Date in both Universal Time and Standard Time

Tags: java

Writing a Java application that takes user input into a Time and Date class, but I am not sure how to take this user input and convert it into Universal and Standard time... I have spent multiple hours surfing the web and stack overflow and have not been able to find a solution.

I have hours, minutes, seconds, year, month, day all in separate integer variables and need to display them in Universal and Standard time.

Thanks for taking a look...

Comment: Which one do you have in your variables? UTC, or local time?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "standard time"? I suspect you mean "local time" in some particular time zone - which time zone? And are your hours/minutes/seconds/year/month/day meant to represent a universal time to start with, or a local time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions:
first is place all of input in the string and parse it:

```
String dateStr = ""
//put your input in this string in some format/ example:
//dateSttr = year + "." + month + "." + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute;
//It is better to use StringBuilder

DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm");
//note that hh is 12h-format and HH is 24h-format
DateFormat outputFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("your_outputFormat");
DateFormat outputFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("your_another_outputFormat");
Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateStr);
String o1, o2;
o1 = outputFormat1.format(date);
o2 = outputFormat2.format(date);
//o1 and o2 is your result.
```

For the rules, how this formats is done, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

The second solution is to get a new date and set your parameters:

```
Calendar cln = Calendar.getInstance().clear(); 
//by default you get a calendar with current system time

//now set the fields. for example, day:
cln.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
cln.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
cln.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);
cln.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);//Calendar.HOUR for 12h-format
cln.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 27);
```

See more about setting calendar in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
Note, that in the second variant, you might have some fields undefiend.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use parts of your code to build a solution

Answer (score 1):

If @JonSkeet 's assumption and mine is correct, you're starting with either UTC or your local time. Displaying it is just a matter of formatting your output.

For the other type of time, you add or subtract a number of hours, which you can find on the web. The tricky part is that this may push you into the next calendar day, or pull you back into the previous one. To deal with that, I figure you want to either

1. implement an adder for year, month, day, hour--or
2. convert those to decimal somethings (Excel uses days, for instance, where as I write this it's 42328.08813), shift the value by the appropriate number of hours, and convert it back.

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time to answer, your suggestions helped me find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

[The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33820846/642706) by [TEXHIK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3913440/texhik) is correct, but outdated. Also, as others mentioned, I do not know what you mean by "Universal and Standard time". But I'll try to get you part way there.

As of Java 8, the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes have been supplanted by the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

The `ZonedDateTime` class has a factory method taking numbers for year, month, and so on.

Plus you must specify a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). If your numbers represent a date-time in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), use the [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) constant. For other time zones, specify a `ZoneId` object by using a proper time zone name; never use the 3-4 letter codes such as `EST` or `IST` as their are neither standardized nor unique.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
// ZoneId zoneId = ZoneOffset.UTC; // ZoneOffset is a subclass of ZoneId.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2015 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , zoneId );
```

> zdt: 2015-01-02T03:04:05.000000006-05:00[America/Montreal]

You can convert to UTC or another time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt_Kolkata = zdt.withZoneSameInstant ( ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata") );
ZonedDateTime zdt_Utc = zdt.withZoneSameInstant ( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

> zdt_Kolkata: 2015-01-02T13:34:05.000000006+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
>
> zdt_Utc: 2015-01-02T08:04:05.000000006Z

If working with classes not yet updated for java.time, convert to a java.util.Date. First extract a [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object, a moment on the timeline always in UTC.

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from ( zdt.toInstant () );
```